# How to align the text in qtreewidget column in this manner : "...qtreewidgetitemdata" instead of "qtreewidgetitemdata..."?

Tags: c++, qt, qtreewidget

How to align data in column 1 of qtreewidget in this manner:

```
|Column1 |Column2|
|+...abcd|efgh   |
|+...ijkl|mnop   |
```

instead of

```
|Column1 |Column2|
|+xyab...|efgh   |
|+pqij...|mnop   |
```

Comment: Maybe consider using `QFontMetrics::elidedText()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to establish the elide mode with a delegate:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

class ElideLeftDelegate: public QStyledItemDelegate
{
public:
    using QStyledItemDelegate::QStyledItemDelegate;
protected:
    void initStyleOption(QStyleOptionViewItem *option, const QModelIndex &index) const{
        QStyledItemDelegate::initStyleOption(option, index);
        option->textElideMode = Qt::ElideLeft;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QTreeWidget w;
    w.setItemDelegateForColumn(0, new ElideLeftDelegate{&w});
    w.setColumnCount(2);
    new QTreeWidgetItem(&w, {"abcdefghijklmnopqrdstuvwxyz", "AVCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"});
    new QTreeWidgetItem(&w, {"AVCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", "abcdefghijklmnopqrdstuvwxyz"});
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

[image]